# Assign a percentage of match to a text field based on another text field

Tags: excel

In using Mirosoft Excel 2010 I am trying to come up a percentage match field.

I have a pipe delimited cell with values such as |37|3P|61|FE|LJ|R7|WL|

I have another area where I can enter values such as |37|LJ|WL|

I want to see how many of the ones I entered |37|LJ|WL|, exist in the dataset (one cell) |37|3P|61|FE|LJ|R7|WL|

What I tried doing was splitting out my values into different cells. One of |37|, one for |LJ| etc, and then doing a find on the dataset cell. The issue I run into this approach is I can't count or add the values from multiple finds.

Any way I can achieve this or any hints would be great!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dataset is in `A1` and the split values are in `B1:B10` then try this formula to count how many of the `B1:B10` values are in `A1`

`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1,"*"&B1:B10&"*")*(B1:B10<>""))`

Comment: Thank you this works great except for one thing. If I enter a single character that matches it counts it. For example the data set is:
|37|3P|61|FE|LJ|R7|WL|

if I enter just P, it add its as one. I need it to match 3P specifically.

Comment: OK, assuming  you enter B1:B10 values **without pipes** then this version will match 3P but not P - `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1,"*|"&B1:B10&"|*"))` - it's not case-sensitive, though, 3p will also match